# iphone update app old users vs new users

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am developing an app that has an sqlite file embedded inside.

That sqlite file is being copied to the /documents folder of the app, and contains the data of a specific version of a book (it's an advanced search app for a specific book).

I've also implemented an subscription service (via inapp payments) for that app, for updating the content. **for Registered users only**. Basically the app update will occur once a large number of update entries is fulfilled or a bug fix, so that the newer user would have to download a lesser number of updates.

The problem is that the old users have paid for a specific book. New users could pay for the extra book, at the same price (consider it an updated version). Is there any way to "forbid" the old users from having access to that book resources since they have not paid a subscription or the app at a latter time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different types of inapp purchases:  non-replenishable, replenishable, subscriptions, and auto-renewing subscriptions.

The user will always get what's embedded, though, if you don't track user status yourself (which *probably* is not worth it) - and then you have to deal with the problem of giving him that exact version.

The main question remains though: Do you really want to penalize your early buyers? Their money came to you first (so it is more worth than the current buy), and now they are left behind with less.

If there is really new content frequently, you might want to go the subscription route. Personally, losing my purchased data like a book just because you bring an update would leave you with one frustrated customer less.

A different route is to limit the support for that app to a specific date and then get your users to buy a new (different) App, maybe with making the first app cheaper during its final stages, and then removing it altogether.

You should aim to make your users buy as soon as possible. But with your business model, it is actually better to buy as late as possible, and often late equals never in practice.